# Can I import a Golang package based on the OS I'm building for?

Tags: go, upstart, launchd, systemd, sysv

Say I have a go project that based on which OS, and in some cases which distro, I want to use say a Systemd client package vs an Upstart client package vs a sysv client package vs a launchd client package.  Is it possible to selectively import each package so I only import the one I need per OS/distro I'm building for?  Or do I have to import each package for each OS/distro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [Package build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> A build constraint, also known as a build tag, is a line comment that
>   begins
>
> ```
> // +build
> ```
>
> that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the
>   package. Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just
>   Go), but they must appear near the top of the file, preceded only by
>   blank lines and other line comments. These rules mean that in Go files
>   a build constraint must appear before the package clause.
>
> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series
>   of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.
>
> A build constraint is evaluated as the OR of space-separated options;
>   each option evaluates as the AND of its comma-separated terms; and
>   each term is an alphanumeric word or, preceded by !, its negation.
>   That is, the build constraint:
>
> ```
> // +build linux,386 darwin,!cgo
> ```
>
> corresponds to the boolean formula:
>
> ```
> (linux AND 386) OR (darwin AND (NOT cgo))
> ```
>
> A file may have multiple build constraints. The overall constraint is
>   the AND of the individual constraints. That is, the build constraints:
>
> ```
> // +build linux darwin
> // +build 386
> ```
>
> corresponds to the boolean formula:
>
> ```
> (linux OR darwin) AND 386
> ```
>
> During a particular build, the following words are satisfied:
>
> ```
> - the target operating system, as spelled by runtime.GOOS
> - the target architecture, as spelled by runtime.GOARCH
> - the compiler being used, either "gc" or "gccgo"
> - "cgo", if ctxt.CgoEnabled is true
> - "go1.1", from Go version 1.1 onward
> - "go1.2", from Go version 1.2 onward
> - "go1.3", from Go version 1.3 onward
> - "go1.4", from Go version 1.4 onward
> - "go1.5", from Go version 1.5 onward
> - "go1.6", from Go version 1.6 onward
> - any additional words listed in ctxt.BuildTags
> ```
>
> If a file's name, after stripping the extension and a possible _test
>   suffix, matches any of the following patterns:
>
> ```
> *_GOOS
> *_GOARCH
> *_GOOS_GOARCH
> ```
>
> (example: source_windows_amd64.go) where GOOS and GOARCH represent any
>   known operating system and architecture values respectively, then the
>   file is considered to have an implicit build constraint requiring
>   those terms (in addition to any explicit constraints in the file).
>
> To keep a file from being considered for the build:
>
> ```
> // +build ignore
> ```
>
> (any other unsatisfied word will work as well, but “ignore” is
>   conventional.)
>
> To build a file only when using cgo, and only on Linux and OS X:
>
> ```
> // +build linux,cgo darwin,cgo
> ```
>
> Such a file is usually paired with another file implementing the
>   default functionality for other systems, which in this case would
>   carry the constraint:
>
> ```
> // +build !linux,!darwin !cgo
> ```
>
> Naming a file dns_windows.go will cause it to be included only when
>   building the package for Windows; similarly, math_386.s will be
>   included only when building the package for 32-bit x86.
>
> Using GOOS=android matches build tags and files as for GOOS=linux in
>   addition to android tags and files.

Use build constraints.

Use a single package with multiple files. Each file specializes for a particular OS, architecture, etc, combination.

Answer (score 2):

> A build constraint is evaluated as the OR of space-separated options; each option evaluates as the AND of its comma-separated terms; and each term is an alphanumeric word or, preceded by !

Actually, that will change [with Go 1.17](https://twitter.com/golang/status/1403016905179422723) (Q3 2021)

> ### `//go:build` lines
>
> The `go` command now understands `//go:build` lines and prefers them over `// +build` lines.
>
> The new syntax uses boolean expressions, just like Go, and should be less error-prone.
>
> As of this release, the new syntax is fully supported, and all Go files should be updated to have both forms with the same meaning.
> To aid in migration, `gofmt` now automatically synchronizes the two forms.
> For more details on the syntax and migration plan, see https://golang.org/design/draft-gobuild.

From the design document:

> The core idea of the design is to replace the current `// +build` lines for build tag selection with new `//go:build` lines that use more familiar boolean expressions.
>
> For example, the old syntax
>
> ```golang
> // +build linux
> // +build 386
> ```
>
> would be replaced by the new syntax
>
> ```golang
> //go:build linux && 386
> ```